# set Element in external Url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to set a value in a Textbox which is present in external url. Im currently using this snippet

```
function func(){
    var childPage = window.open("extenal url(like www.google.com)");
    var textbox = childPage.document.getElemntsByName('textboxName')[0];
     textbox.value ="something";
}
```

But i'm getting "Access is denied" while retrieving the element ref.

Can we set any textbox of extenal url within our application by any other way.
Thanks

Comment: [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, No. If browsers allowed this there would be **serious** security flaws.

The only way you can update your textbox is by running the JavaScript from **within** the website in the iframe.

You would then do `parent.document.getElementsByName('textboxName')[0];`